# Error al intentar actualizar datos crud node.js express (Cannot get edit/!) tiene que llevar un dato al nuevo formulario para realizar update

Tags: nodejs, express, sqlite

Hasta el momento he intentado seguir tutoriales, y aunque sigo al pie de la letra no funciona, sigue apareciendo el mismo error

```
//POST /crear
app.post('/agregar', (req, res) => {
  const sql="INSERT INTO users(email, hashed_password) VALUES(?,?)";
  const nuevo_user=[req.body.email, req.body.password];
  //const nuevo_user=["pruebain1@in.co","1234"]
  db.all(sql, nuevo_user, Error=>{
  if (Error){
    return console.error(Error.message);
  } else{
    console.log("Registro insertado correctamente");

  //GET /Editar/id
  app.get("/editar/:id",(req, res)=>{
    const id=req.params.id;
    const sql="SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=?";

    db.get(sql,id,(rows)=>{
      res.render("editar.ejs", { modelo:  rows })
    })
  });
```

Comment: El metodo crear funciona perfecto, también tengo uno que me carga la BD perfecto, pero cuando trato de llevar uno especifico me aparece ese error de cannot get, (y el nombre del archivo ejs está bien)

Comment: Lo que has puesto como comentario en realidad son más detalles a tu pregunta. Pulsa en [edit] para agregarlo a la misma. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes un error de estructura y el código que has puesto no parece que funcione. Talvez un error de copiado y pegado. Aun así primero valida que los endpoint funcionen bien simplificandolos lo más posible:

```javascript
    // /POST /crear
    app.post("/agregar", (req, res) => {
      return res.send("Post esta funcionando");
    });
    
    //GET /Editar/id
    app.get("/editar/:id", (req, res) => {
      return res.send("Get esta funcionando");
    });
```